# Диапазон строкового типа в swift

Tags: ios, swift, range

В книге Усова написано, что могут быть диапазоны строкового типа, но вот как они работают не написано, также хотелось бы узнать, какое им есть применение и какие элементы содержатся в диапазоне.
Пример: "aa"..<"zz"

Comment: Так спросили бы непосредственно у Усова :) У него же телеграм канал есть очень активный и группа в ВК.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такие диапазоны работают по правилу сортировки на основании сравнения элементов (поэтому диапазоны должны реализовать `Comparable`), можно сравнить результат с сортировкой массивов

```
var range = "abc"..<"z"

var arr1 = ["abc", "z", "a"]
var arr2 = ["abc", "z", "b"]

arr1.sort()
arr2.sort()

print(arr1)
print(range.contains("a")) // false

print(arr2)
print(range.contains("b")) // true
```

Вывод

```
["a", "abc", "z"]
false
["abc", "b", "z"]
true
```